# Mysql triggers passing data from one table to another matching tables

Tags: mysql, triggers

I've table1 with columns (id, firstname, lastname) and table2 with columns (id, firstname, lastname, ans3, mandate, matchid). So far i've made this trigger that inserts firstname and lastname from table1 to table2. Now the thing that i want is to join the matchid from table2 with the id from table1. For example when matchid = 1 display records from table1 with id = 1 and in the same row the table2 records. Here's what i do so far with the trigger.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER after_user_insert AFTER INSERT ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

  INSERT INTO table2 (firstname, lastname, matchid)
  VALUES (NEW.firstname, NEW.lastname, NEW.id);

END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

Here's a photo of what i get in phpmyadmin. You can see that i didn't figure how to join table2.matchid to table1.id

[image: You can see that i didn't figure how to join table2.matchid to table1.id]

---**edit**---
[image]

Comment: Do you realize that the `id` in your screen capture belongs to `table2` and not `table1`?  In general, don't worry about the value of an auto increment column.  Just let MySQL manage it for you.

Comment: yes @TimBiegeleisen i realize that, but what i mean is that the data 7.0 and 2017-10-16 should be in the same row with John Doe (please see the capture).

Comment: Aha!  Do you really want to _update_ a user record to the latest values instead of inserting a new record?

Comment: i'll give an example in order to explain better with the capture! the 7.0 and 2017-10-16 should be in the same raw with John Doe as i mentioned! The 26.1 ans 2017-10-16 is a second measurement (lets suppose in the same day) of John Doe as well, so they should be displayed in the same raw as well. Then, i want to insert a different person for example Jane Doe and be able to match the data to her just like i did with John!

Comment: `so they should be displayed in the same raw as well` ... this makes no sense to me.  Maybe you should _show_ us what output you actually want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comments it sounds like perhaps you intended to update a user record which already exists in `table2`.  If so, you can use `ON DUPLICATE KEY` when you update:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER after_user_insert AFTER INSERT ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO table2 (firstname, lastname, matchid)
    VALUES (NEW.firstname, NEW.lastname, NEW.id)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE matchid = NEW.id;

END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

This solution would require that there is a unique index on both the first and last name in `table2`.  If you don't have such a unique index, then you can add one:

```
ALTER TABLE table2 ADD UNIQUE unq_idx (firstname, lastname);
```

Comment: so, i have to drop first the previous trigger and insert this insted? and also, this script will allow to insert new persons from table1 to table2 as it was possibled with the previous trigger?

Comment: Hold on...show us what output you want after three inserts to `table2` for the same user.  My answer is right if you want the latest insert to take effect.  It is wrong if you want something else.

Comment: aha i see! i just provided an example of how the table2 should display if i insert data from different people and how they should be matched!

Comment: Doing multiple inserts on `table1` will by definition mean a new auto incremented `id` value for each insert, and hence a new `matchid` in `table2`.  Maybe you can shed some light on what is going on in `table1` which then should fire a trigger in `table2`.

Comment: no, there is the misunderstanding i think! the matchid is an input field that i can define its value and submit it via html form. So matchid is not the primary key in table2 and it's not auto increment.

Comment: Now I'm confused.  Your trigger is assigning `matchid` a value, via the insert on `table1`.  Now I question whether you should even be using a trigger here.

Comment: yes i understand what you mean! it's too complicated and i'm trying to combine these data with views, joins and now triggers for a week but still no solution found!

Comment: Edit your question and describe, in clear language, the exact flow you have involving both your tables.  If articulated correctly, it would then be obvious what needs to be done.